# Django HTML-how to make the title of an object 'clickable' and direct to detail display page after clicking

Tags: python, html, django

Sorry if this question is a bit general, I am learning web development in django and trying to figure out how the html functions & interacts.

Now,there is a simple page display.html,taking a set of objects(e.g book) and display the title of the book.

Normally,the title of each book would be a link , clicking on the title link will direct to another page displaying the detailed info of this book(e.g. title, author)

But after searching through for long, I am still confused on how this could be done.

Below is the code for display.html.

```
<table>
{% for instance in book %}
<li>{{ instance.title }}</li>
{% endfor %}   
</table>
```

I guess there should be a function in the view.py accepting the id of a certain book and when you click on the tile of book,the id is passed to this function, and the function will pass the exact book object to a detail_display.html

Please correct me I am wrong and give some suggestion on how this could be done. Thanks very much!

Comment: [Part 3](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/intro/tutorial03/) of the tutorial covers this in detail. If you still have questions after reading that, come back and update us.

Comment: Hi Burhan, thank you so much !after following through, now I could search,list all the book objects,make the book clickable and direct me to the detail page.

Comment: @Burhan there is one more problem, the detail display page cannot display the attributes. My code is {% for fields in position %}
    <li>{{ field }}{{ value }}</li>
{% endfor %} but there is error info showing 'book' object is not iterable. In the reference provided by you,I think it is because Poll have a set of choice_set objects, so can be iterated through. So the question is, how to make iterate through the fields of the book object and display.(Also,can I make some constrains on what fields to display?) really thanks. :)

Comment: `{{ position.field_name }}`, since `position` is your object in the detail view; and in the example in the tutorial its a collection of objects.

Comment: Okie, understand it now. So I would have to type and list the {{position.fieldname}} myself in the html right? I am thinking if there is some other ways that I can iterate the fields of the the position object and display its content(i.e. using a for loop to do so instead of typing the field to be displayed)

Comment: yea, listing the fields manually is working fine now, but there shall be some more automatic ways to do this, can you give some suggestions? Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

The *usual* way I approach this in Django is to implement the [`get_absolute_url()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/instances/#get-absolute-url) function for the particular model class, i.e. `Book` in your case.

Resulting template code would be:

```
{% for b in book %}
<li>
    <a href="{{ b.get_absolute_url }}">{{ b.title }}</a>
</li>
{% endfor %}
```